# Websocket server and npm start on localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, websocket

Out of boredom I currently try to create a simple chat-app on my localhost.

To start this all out, I began with a plain react app based on create-react-app.
In there I have the following code to start a WebSocket communication.

```js
  // on localhost:3000
  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.ws = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:5000');

    this.ws.on('open', () => {
      this.ws.send(this.props.userName + ' has joined the Chat.');
    });

    this.ws.on('message', (message) => {
      const messages = this.state.messages;
      this.state.messages.push(message)
      this.setState({ messages: messages })
    });

    console.log('Component mounted.')
  }
```

Whenever I try this at runtime with `npm start` to communicate with the counterpart WebSocket server that looks like the following and started on the same machine with `node server.js`

```js
// File: server.js
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 5000 });

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
    ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
        console.log('received: %s', message);
    });

    ws.send('something');
});
```

I get the following issue:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

To solve this I've already tried:

1. Access-Control-Allow-Origin extension for chrome no effect.
2. To set the following proxy in package.json `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"` - also no effect.
3. As a kind of last resort I tried to launch google-chrome with `google chrome --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=/tmp` - in this case i get the following: `GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/ net::ERR_ABORTED 426 (Upgrade Required)` and from here on I'm lost.

Can anyone help me out on this issue? Would this be possible in general or is there a flaw in my thinking?

I'm not a webdeveloper of anykind and usually do C++... Sorry if that all seems stupid.

Regards
Jack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you are using the native WebSocket object on the client and not a "browserified" one.

So an import like `import WebSocket from "ws"` must not exist in your React app. The WebSocket constructor statement will remain as it is.

This is because ws needs a plain TCP socket and there is no way to get one in the browser via JavaScript (that's why WebSocket API exists).

The following issue might help you with more details:-
https://github.com/websockets/ws/issues/1367

Comment: Thanks! That actually solved it. I removed the import ws statement and had to modify the ws.on() method to ws.addEventListener()

Answer (score 0):

I encountered something like this using PHP on Amazon AWS. But it went away I think without my doing anything, and the reason I believe this happened was AWS on its own started including the Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* header.

In any case:

A simple fix would be to try changing this

```
ws://127.0.0.1:5000
```

to this

```
ws://locahost:5000
```

Otherwise add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* on your server side to the response headers

Comment: unfortunately your proposal doesn't change anything for me - I still get the upgrade required statement. And how would I add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* on my 'server side' if it's just hosted locally with node? Is that even possible?